# Change DIV content based on list item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of cateogries in a web page, I'd like to change the content of a div in the page based on the item clicked. I have seen examples with Dropdown menu but none with list items. Let's suppose I have this list :

```
<ul class="nav-sidebar">
  <li><a  href="#">elem1</a></li>
  <li> <a  href="#">elem2</a></li>
  <li> <a  href="#">elem3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="div1">this is div 1</div>
<div id="div2">this is div 2</div>
<div id="div3">this is div 3</div>
```

For example, when user clicks elem1 the div with div1 would be displayed in a sliding motion?

This is the example I found : http://jsfiddle.net/cqDES/1540/

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? what exactly are you stuck on? What in the "example that you have found" doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes I have tried and what I mean is I want the click on the item list to trigger the transition of the div. The content of the div changes based on the item clicked

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cqDES/1558/

Comment: So what's your question? There is a distinct lack of `?`? This looks a lot like a "givez mez the codez" question

Comment: That's exactly what is it. Cause this problem represents 0.00001% of the rest of my current problems hahah thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the same behaviour but change to a list you can do:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-sidebar li').click(function() {
      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
      $('div:not(#div' + index + ')').slideUp();
      $('#div' + index).slideDown();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqDES/1552/